# My game of Rummikub came with a die. Why could that be?

Tags: rummikub

My newly bought, first-hand game of Rummikub (from [Philos](https://web.archive.org/web/20111130080110/http://www.kontor68.eu/p/77018/philos-rummy-in-kunstlederkoffer)) came with a die. However, the game doesn't seem to use a die. Is there any variant that uses a die, if so, what for?

Comment: Was this a second-hand copy, or new in box?

Comment: @goldPseudo It was newly bought; see update.

Comment: That does confuse the issue.  I'm tempted to go out and buy myself a new copy just to see if this is actually a *thing* rather than a bizarre packing mistake; I have never before needed a die when playing.

Comment: The company Antochia Crafts sell a wood set on Amazon (ASIN B07R1NSHSH). The materials list includes "1 dice" (sic). Their rules are not available on their website. Maybe someone who owns this expensive set can answer.

Answer (score 7):

There *is* a game called [Dice Rummikub](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/9017/rummikub-rummy-dice-game), which uses dice instead of tiles; while related, it is its own game and requires more than a single die.

Short of being mixed into the box accidentally, or tossed in as a convenient first-player randomizer (because "high tile goes first" is just *so* complicated :p), I can't think of any reason for its inclusion in the regular tile-based Rummikub set.

Answer (score 4):

I could be misremembering (I couldn't find a source), but I think my old set of Rummikub might  have included a die purely to decide who goes first.

I definitely remember buying a game that included a die that was only used to see who goes first. I remember only because it seemed so absurd as there are [many other ways](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/2043/1749) to decide who goes first.

Comment: Couldn't you just pick tiles to determine starting player?

Answer (score 0):

I use to play this with my grandparents all the time and we used the dice to determine who went first, tho alot of players use a high tile for this as well we didn't know what else to do with the dice so that's what we used it for. I sure miss tho days some of my best memories love to hear others making those same amazing memories they last a life time cherish your loved ones ❤

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but your answer should probably be a comment on the question or one of the answers rather than in the form of an answer itself, as it doesn't seem to provide any new information.